# How to change case of certain letters in input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to js/jquery (obviously) and am working on a small project that involves changing the case to toUpperCase on all letters except for "o", which will remain/change to lowercase.

I have implemented this: http://jsfiddle.net/HwTEj/

```
$(function() {
$('input').keyup(function() {
this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    });
});
```

however I am struggling to define certain letters to remain/change to lowercase.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, and since I am new to posting questions to SO please let me know if there is any additional info you need to point me in the right direction.

Comment: After you converted the string, replace every occurrence of `O` with `o`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To replace all instances you will need something like this:

```
this.value.toUpperCase().replace(/O/g, "o")
```

EDIT:

If you want to have a selection of characters that will be replaced you could do this (using o, f and h as an example here):

```
this.value.toUpperCase().replace(/[OFH]/g, function($1){ 
    return $1.toLowerCase();
  })
```

Comment: both answers (this and updated fiddle via rwisch45) work great - however I will mark this as my accepted answer due to the simple use of replace method. thank you all for the quick responses to a pretty obvious (for you) question!

Comment: If you elect to do this, note that you'll be upcasing and replacing the entire value on every kepress!

Answer (score 2):

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/HwTEj/231/)

```
$(function() {
    $('input').keyup(function() {
        this.value = this.value.toUpperCase().split('O').join('o');      
    });
});
```

Comment: While technically correct, there is no point to adding confusion by using split/join instead of a simple replace, which is what that method is for.

Comment: @IngoBürk agreed. upvoted koosa's solution as the better answer

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are good, but here's an alternative:

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/(o)|./ig, function(x, y) { 
    return y ? y.toLowerCase() : x.toUpperCase(); 
});
```

You can replace `o` in the pattern with a character class (e.g. `[xyz]`) if you need to make other characters lower case.